# Mass change in deamidation from Glutamine to Glutamate

Tags: mass-spec

To detect the deamidation from Glutamine to Glutamate in a protein, normal practise seems to be a mass spec, where it is claimed there is a change of 1 dalton.

EG [It is claimed](http://www.ionsource.com/Card/Deamidation/mono0001.htm) that:

> Deamidation of an Asn to Asp/IsoAsp results in an increase in mass of a single dalton.

But when I look at their table, they are using Glutamic Acid as being 1 Dalton heavier than Glutamate, but at pH 7 the Glutamic Acid will be deprotonated to Glutamate. Do they  put the sample in pH 4 to protonate the Glutamate first? But then you are risking catalysing the hydrolysis of Glutamine anyway, rendering your results useless!

There should be a charge difference though, as you are going from neutral to a negative charge, so that would show up in a change in mass/charge on the mass spec, rather than a mass change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be better on chemistry SE.

Comment: Its more relevant to Biology as its to do with Proteins I think.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area but this is what I understand. Usually ESI based protein mass spec imparts a positive charge on the proteins by protonation. Formic acid is usually added to help in protonation. In deamidation `-NH2` is replaced by `-OH` thereby increasing the mass by 1 dalton (14+2 -> 16+1). I think that glutamine may be also acquire multiple charge (by NH2 protonation). You can see this [article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac3013362), which talks about dealing with deamidation artifacts resulting from sample preparation techniques.

Comment: Ah, so the samples are put in acidic conditions to protonate the glutamate which can result in false positives, interesting.

Comment: Biochemistry is still chemistry :)

Comment: Are you performing native or non-native MS?

Comment: @harpalss I'm currently reading papers/data from other sources and was trying to work out how they were doing it. The details seem to be glossed over rather a lot!

Comment: I do alot of ESI mass spec, so i might be able to help. Alot of my work is on native MS. Are you looking at the whole protein in the mass spec or a peptide fragment?